# Laravel hasone relation explain

Tags: laravel, eloquent

[image]

**return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');**

I need hasone relationship in these two tables.

in both tables, the relation should be in between username column in both parent and child table, not id in parent and username or any other in child.
Please explain 3rd parameter in above hasone function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So, your user has passport, right? Then, in your user Model you need to write the following method to manage this relationship:

```
public function passport(){
    return $this->hasOne(Passport::class, 'username', 'username');
}
```

Here, I think you know about the 1st parameter, It's the model(class) name of the relational table. The 2nd parameter is the foreign key which means the column in `passports` table which define the relationship with `users` If you don't pass this second argument it will be `user_id` by default.

**3rd Parameter**

Third parameter is is the column name(local key) of your `users` table which is mentioned as a relationship in your `passports` table. By If you don't pass the 3rd parameter then by default this is `id`. In your case, as you are connecting your `users` username with the `passports` tables username. So, `users` table's `username`(3rd parameter) is related to the `passports table's`username`(2nd parameter).

Comment: It is very useful can you extend your answer with inverse relation. It would be great

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter is a local key column in the `users` table. So the relationship should look like this:

```
public function passport()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Passport', 'username', 'username');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

hasOne(Phone::class);
    }
}

The first argument passed to the hasOne method is the name of the related model class. Once the relationship is defined, we may retrieve the related record using Eloquent's dynamic properties. Dynamic properties allow you to access relationship methods as if they were properties defined on the model:

$phone = User::find(1)->phone;

Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the parent model name. In this case, the Phone model is automatically assumed to have a user_id foreign key. If you wish to override this convention, you may pass a second argument to the hasOne method:

return $this->hasOne(Phone::class, 'foreign_key');

Additionally, Eloquent assumes that the foreign key should have a value matching the primary key column of the parent. In other words, Eloquent will look for the value of the user's id column in the user_id column of the Phone record. If you would like the relationship to use a primary key value other than id or your model's $primaryKey property, you may pass a third argument to the hasOne method:

return $this->hasOne(Phone::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');

Comment: Please read [How do I format my posts with Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)